# Accesing my ObservableCollection from another class

Tags: c#, class

Hi so i have created an ObservableCollection for my game which works perfect with my bindings etc. Now i just have the problem i cannot access it from other classes. Have tried out most things but I'm probably missing some obvious things.

Thanks in advance!

```
namespace Game1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public ObservableCollection<Pieces> GamePiece{ get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
       GamePiece= new ObservableCollection<Pieces>();

       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = ChessItem;
       // Here i can add GamePiece.add(new Pieces() ....) etc which works
    }
}
 //Another file
 namespace Game1
 {
    public class test1
    {
       public test1()
       {
         //How to access GamePiece from here? Like GamePiece.add(etc)
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot say GamePiece.Add inside another class as GamePiece is not a type, but rather a property inside another type. There're two ways you can access it

1. You either make that property static, so that you don't have to instanciate the MainWindow class and access it like this:

   ```
   MainWindow.GamePiece.Add(new Piece());
   ```
2. You leave it as it is but this time create an instance of the MainWindow class and then access it through that object, like this:

   (new MainWindow()).GamePiece.Add(new Piece());

or to make it look more elegant

```
    MainWindow mw=new MainWindow();
    mn.GamePiece.Add(new Piece());
```

To be honest, I have never done WPF before. I'm just reminding the proper way of accessing a property on another type.

Comment: Ad 1. Do you really believe that binding to static view properties is the right direction to teach someone about WPF? Ad 2. Assuming that you actually want to utilize the `MainWindow` class as a ... well, WPF Window, which is probably already instantiated by the application, what's the purpose of this?

Comment: You know, you're right about this specific case. Neither of the approaches are the ones I would encourage someone to take. But I felt a lack of good understanding of how accessing fields of a class should be, so I chose to go generic way. I mean, I just explained that the way the OP is trying to access a property in another type is wrong. Otherwise, you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

If make your GamePiece-collection static,

```
public static ObservableCollection<Pieces> GamePiece{ get; set; }
```

and then in Game1 you can access it with

```
MainWindow.GamePiece
```

Comment: OP clearly states that he uses the `ObservableCollection` for binding. Static properties have some limitations when used in the WPF data binding pattern and as such should be avoided (e.g. it's a one time binding, providing a new collection will never reflect on the UI, if you took the fancy to do so).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry i missed that part. Never mind my answer since you are totally correct @decPL

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of accessing your collection, it's a question of getting a reference to your `MainWindow` object. A simple, slightly naive approach would be something like so:

```
var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().Single();
var gamePiece = mainWindow.GamePiece;
```

A better way to go about it would be to employ one of the `MV*` patterns, separating your model from your code behind and passing the reference to your model to the code where you want to use it. Giving you all the necessary details is pretty much out of scope for a single SO answer, but here's some [starting point](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html) (note: that's pretty much reinventing the wheel; once you know the basics, it's better to use some existing MVVM library, e.g. [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)).

Comment: Thanks alot, i'll defintely be looking into MVVM more!

Answer (score 0):

While changing this property to static will work (while possibly creating other issues in the future).
You need to consider why do you have a class accessing a window's data context and manipulating it, while not actually having a reference to that window's instance.

Consider having a dedicated class for the data context, and have it's instance injected to both the window and "test1", that way they both have access to it, and can manipulate it without the MainWindow being coupled to "test1".

For a more in depth look on this concept, check out the [MVVM design pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained).

Also note that if you perform action on this *ObservableCollection* from a thread that isn't the UI thread, you will get an exception because it owned by the UI Thread. 
To solve that you should use the Dispatcher class, that will delegate the manipulation action to the UI Thread from other background threads.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will be looking into more with the MVVM design, looks so smooth when you know how to handle it. Would upvote if i hade the rep for it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you can create static property like this:

```
private static MainWindow _instance = null;
public static MainWindow Instannce => _instance ?? (_instance = new MainWindow ());
```

access to all public property  in your class like this:

```
MainWindow.Instannce.GamePiece.Add(new Piece());
```